# Java Regex Matcher encountering NullPointerException, when handed null input

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am trying to use the java regex matcher-class and I'm encountering a NullPointerException in my code:

```
String input = null;
System.out.println("\nEnter your username: ");
Matcher matcher = VALID_USERNAME_REGEX.matcher(input); //EXCEPTION IS HERE
if (matcher.find()) {
    username = input;
} else {
    input = null;
    System.out.println("\nInvalid input, please try again!");
}
```

**Stack Trace:** (line: 173 is in the above code where the comment "`//EXCEPTION IS HERE`" is located)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Unknown Source)
    at org.console.Interface.createAccount(Interface.java:173)
    at org.console.Interface.login(Interface.java:78)
    at org.application.Application.run(Application.java:31)
    at org.application.Application.main(Application.java:37)
```

The value of the input should be what the user enters in the console. The regex should match the input to validate that it meets the regex requirements.

Comment: Can you post your stack trace and the value of `input`?

Comment: added to bottom of post

Comment: seems like `input` is `null` , try to print `input` before `matcher`

Comment: @Brenton unless you left out some code `input` is NOT what the user entered.

Comment: @Henry thanks for the comment,  that was my issue.

Comment: Instead of adding the solution to the question, can you remove it from the question and self answer this question? Answers don't really belong in the question.

Comment: Note to the author, the duplicate closure doesn't mean the question was bad in any way. It covers an undocumented NullPointerException in a commonly used API. It just means the question is answerable through an equivalent/more general questions answers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not explicitly stated in the javadoc of [`Pattern#matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matcher-java.lang.CharSequence-), but it will not work with a `null` input (it creates a new [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) instance which will reset itself upon initialization, leading to the observed exception). You'll have to explicitly test for `!= null` beforehand.

Side note: Although undocumented, this has [already been declined to change](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6178785):

> The current API doc does not explicitly or implicitly mention whether
>   or not a NPE will/should be thrown. But it is difficult to define a
>   good semantics for a "null" in Matcher as a legal input text, should
>   it be semantically equivalent to empty string ""? Obviously not. 
>   Then, what the match/find result should be expected when match null
>   against boundary pattern like "^" and "$" (probably no match/no find
>   for all patterns), and who will be benefited from such a semantics?
>   The described use scenario is reasonable but should be easily achieved
>   by use an empty string "" instead.  Dont see a strong justification to
>   "fix" the current behavior. Instead, updating the package spec to
>   describe the NPE behavior might be a better choice.

Answer (score 2):

I added `input = in.nextLine();` above the matcher line.

```
String input = null;
System.out.println("\nEnter your username: ");
input = in.nextLine();
Matcher matcher = VALID_USERNAME_REGEX.matcher(input); //EXCEPTION IS HERE
if (matcher.find()) {
    username = input;
} else {
    input = null;
    System.out.println("\nInvalid input, please try again!");
}
```